# Can I get a reference to an object created in a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perhaps my brain is fried, but I'm writing a plugin that created an tweaks an element, but also creates an object that i'd like access to. So the plugin looks like this

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function () {
    return this.each(function () {

          // do some stuff to the element...

          this.objectInstance = new usefulObject();

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

function usefulObject(){
    // useful object properties and methods....

    this.doSomething = function(){
        alert("Don't google Google. You'll break the internet.");
    }
}
```

so when I call the plugin, I also want to be able to get access to that usefulObject that I created. I thought something like this might work....

```
tweakedElement = $("#someDiv").myPlugin();

tweakedElement.objectInstance.doSomething();
```

... but that's not working. How can I achieve this? Can I achieve this? Answers on a postcard, or down below, whichever suits you.

Comment: Why not do doSomething() within the plugin itself? Or set an option on whether or not to doSomething() within the plugin itself?

Comment: i need to access it later, long after it's been created. The plugin  creates a bunch of SVG paths that I need to access from other parts of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `objectInstance` on the element in question using jQuery's `data` function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

> The jQuery.data() method allows us to
>   attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from
>   circular references and therefore from
>   memory leaks. We can set several
>   distinct values for a single element
>   and retrieve them later